# Optimise camera for QR codes

Tags: iphone, ios8, camera, qr-code, camera-calibration

I have a `AVCaptureDevice` specifically to scan QR codes (using `AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode`). My goal is to make QR code scanning as fast as possible.

Several settings of the `AVCaptureDevice` camera (e.g. [focus](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009520-CH1-SW4) and [exposure](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009520-CH1-SW15)) can be programmatically adjusted in iOS.

What camera optimisations I can make to minimise the time it takes to capture a QR code on an iPhone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of those settings optimal values vary based on the environment (eg dark/bright room, near/far QR Code etc.), so unless you know your user's environment (eg if the app was used exclusively in factory assembly lines), the default is probably best.

However (according to [this source](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2014/05/13/reading-qr-codes.html)), If you know that the QR code will be near the camera you can speed up autofocus by setting [autoFocusRangeRestriction](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVCaptureDevice/autoFocusRangeRestriction) to a near range value. You could also make sure that [smoothAutoFocusEnabled](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVCaptureDevice/smoothAutoFocusEnabled) is set to false.

Answer (score -4):

I was used AVCaptureDevice.
This code working find i was used this in my bar code app.try this code.

```
-(void)BarcodeStart
{

    _highlightView = [[UIView alloc] init];

    _highlightView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;

    _highlightView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
    _highlightView.layer.borderWidth = 3;

    [barcameraView addSubview:_highlightView];

    _label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    _label.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height - 40, self.view.bounds.size.width, 40);
    _label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
    _label.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.15 alpha:0.65];
    _label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    _label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    _label.text = @"(none)";
    [self.view addSubview:_label];
    //BackBtn UP side Show
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    //[button addTarget:self action:@selector(aMethod:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(3,19,30,30);
    img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"backBtnImg.png"];
    [button setImage:img.image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_highlightView addSubview:button];
    //
    _session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    _device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    NSError *error = nil;

    _input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:_device error:&error];
    if (_input) {
        [_session addInput:_input];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }

    _output = [[AVCaptureMetadataOutput alloc] init];
    [_output setMetadataObjectsDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
    [_session addOutput:_output];

    _output.metadataObjectTypes = [_output availableMetadataObjectTypes];

    _prevLayer = [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer layerWithSession:_session];
    // _prevLayer.frame = CGRectMake(20, 70, 280, 280);
    _prevLayer.frame = barcameraView.bounds;
    _prevLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
    [barcameraView.layer addSublayer:_prevLayer];

    [_session startRunning];

    [barcameraView bringSubviewToFront:_highlightView];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:_label];
}
```